# How to set a default value for select_tag in Rails and ensure the default value reloads on page refresh

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery, drop-down-menu, refresh, default-value

**Background**

I have a view page(abc.html.haml) with 2 drop down options A and B. A, B are lists which hold a set of records whose parts I am showcasing through the UI.

By default on hitting the controller#index action(called via browser url), the page populates with the records from the A list.

I then have an Ajax call which populates the same page with the records from list B, on choosing the drop down menu. Let's assume I have now moved from State A to B using the drop down option.

**Issue**

Once, I have the page populated with records from list B, Now, ***upon page refresh***, My drop down menu still holds the same state 'B', but the default set of records which load from the controller#action on page refresh is from the list A(thus the state of the drop down menu should be 'A').

Any inputs on how I can get a work around for this ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if I understand your problem completely, but a few options I can think of:

- Use javascript to change the URL when selections are made in the drop downs.  You could add paramaters to the URL that could reflect the state of the drop downs, you could then parse these on load of the page.
- Give the user a refresh button that you control, then you can send information back to the controller on refresh so that you load the right defaults.
- Store the current users selections in the database via ajax calls as the user makes them.  I don't know the context of your app, so I don't know how feasible this is.  Then you could obviously load these on page load if they exist.

The simplest option however would be to reset all controls on page refresh, I think users expect that behaviour anyway.

Comment: Thanks for your inputs. I am doing an Ajax call via Jquery, as am appropriately passing params as well. The page view gets filtered as per the passed params. Generally users do a browser refresh, how can I reset the select_tag to the default value on page refresh for a view file that is "not" named with the same action name ?. I'm sorry, I realized I missed out on mentioning that the controller#action actually renders another view file, and not the action.html.haml as per the normal Rails convention. Probably this is whats causing the abnormal behavior.